Why would non-kohen soldiers give conditional divorces and not immediate divorces?
I've been reading (for example, here) about how Jewish soldiers since the times of King David have given their wives conditional divorces, that are designed to take effect only if some number of years pass before the husband returns home (i.e. Shabbat 26a, and Ketubot 9b)
Apparently this practice is even continued until this day, as many Israeli soldiers have given their wives such conditional divorces in the event God forbid that they are captured and never found.
What am I wondering is what is the advantage of a conditional divorce as opposed to a regular divorce? Why must there be some delay, or agonizing condition? Why not divorce immediately with a promise to eachother to await a future reunion? This seems to be far simpler and gives both parties the freedom to decide what is best for them given the evolving circumstances.

You'd then have to bother getting remarried?

It's not very common among Israeli soldiers for various reasons, halachic and practical (though every few years some rabbis publish articles and debate if it should be more common). Anytime you go on break to go home for a couple days you may have to write and give another get. And with modern tech etc. it's not nearly as common to never come home.

Because then another man can swoop in and steal his girl

@CuriousYid they could promise to eachother not to remarry for X years. A man can't "swoop in" and marry her without her consent

What good is a promise

@lgshost who said she has no consent. Picture the scenario- a guy loves this girl but can’t do anything bc she’s married. Now one day her husband goes to war and they divorce, so this guy starts cozying up to her until she falls for him and totally forgets about the first husband. Not a crazy case. And now she doesn’t have to even worry about getting a get, she can just marry this guy instantly (perhaps Kiddushin through ביאה )

@DoubleAA Also, the issue with yichud is that he might tell her the get is cancelled.  Do we also have to avoid yichud with a phone (which in my understanding is allowed except for top security deployments)?

@CuriousYid so it's based on the premise that women are "possessions" of men, and that men need to stop other men from taking their possessions? Do women have no agency or rights?

B"H
Getting married is a big deal.
Every marriage is supposed to last forever, ideally. We say in the blessings of nisuin "...an everlasting edifice". Saying the blessings of marriage, paying the kesuvah and then rewriting it, making an additional $50k+ wedding with the proper band, food and accomodations is a big deal.
Many sources in the Torah stress the importance of making a wedding extremely lavish, because it is the foundation of the entire marriage.
Some sources (like the rugichover) even discuss how the entire marriage is one continuous effect that is constantly being renewed every instant, and the cause that makes it become renewed is from the moment of betrothal.
That's one of the many reasons why the day of the wedding is extremely important, and why it's worth it to spend tens or even hundreds of thousands of dollars just for that one day.
According to Shulchan Aruch, the day of the wedding is like a personal Yom Kippur for the bride and the groom. Once one has already gone through all of that trouble it's no light task to simply do it again if there's no need to, there's nothing wrong with a conditional divorce.
A divorce is also a big deal and should be avoided if needed.
The mishnah says that one should never divorce one's wife unless he needs to (there's different opinions within that scope, ranging from being so strict that only if she actually acted immoral/immodestly should one divorce her, to even if he found one more beautiful than her etc., but still, it can't just be for no reason).
Especially when it applies to one's first wife, the Talmud teaches that if someone chose vishalom divorces his first wife, the throne of Glory itself is dripping with tears.
In addition, in the vast majority of cases, when a divorce happens, the husband is obligated to pay her the Kesuvah amount specified at the time of the begining of the marriage. This could involve oftentimes seizing real estate property from people who bought land from the husband during the marriage period, if husband doesn't have enough money to pay back, which could cause all kinds of additional complications and court cases etc.
Also, there's no limit as to how many times one could be called for war.
If it's a one time war, then possibly there might be some thought of a justification to do a full divorce, even with all of the reasons not to in place.
But what if one spends an additional $50k+ and goes through all of the effort to get remarried after the war, then another couple years pass and he's called in to fight again?

You don't need a fancy party for the remarriage. The soldier could be placed into debt for the ketuba and that debt can be later nullified. If he is Israeli, he is not likely to own real estate because almost all Jewish land is actually owned by the state or JNF.
